# Merge duplicate value cells into single cells with same amount space using rowspan

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

```
var arr = ['ar', 'ar', 'ar', 'ar', 'at', 'br', 'de', 'de', 'de', 'jp', 'jp', 'us', 'us', 'us', 'us', 'us', 'us'];

__


ar

__
at
__
br
__

de

__

jp

__



us


__
```

here goes my array of values. This array contains repeating values like `'ar','ar','de','de'` and so on & each values create one row. what i want is how to merge the repeating values in to single cell.Here is my code goes.

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.style.border = '1px solid black';

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    table.appendChild(tr);
    var td_dmxn = document.createElement('td');
    td_dmxn.style.border = "1px solid black";
    td_dmxn.innerHTML = arr[i];
    td_dmxn.style.textAlign = "center";
    var row = arr[i],
            prevRow = arr[i - 1];
    if (prevRow && row === prevRow) {
        td_dmxn.innerHTML = '';

    } else {

    }
    $(tr).append(td_dmxn);
}
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

I dont know where to use rowspan in here. i just emptied the repeating values this is creating empty td's. so please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: Rather than merging the cells, why not remove the duplicates from the array? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Comment: No i want to merge the cells that is my requirement. and the empty cells also provide the equal space.

Comment: provide html expected results when duplicate cells are merged. "Merge" be interpreted several ways

Comment: Place this `$(tr).append(td_dmxn);` in the else part of your if instruction

Comment: My table rows wants to be like this i provided in my latest edits. please someone help me.

Answer (score 1):

Count how often a string is in the array and add this as `rowspan` in the `td_dmxn`

Example without some unnecessary (in respect to the problem) lines:

```js
var arr = ['ar', 'ar', 'ar', 'ar', 'at', 'br', 'de', 'de', 'de', 'jp', 'jp', 'us', 'us', 'us', 'us', 'us', 'us'],
    groups,
    keys,
    table = document.createElement('table'),
    docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    tr,
    td_dmxn,
    i;

// group and count the strings in the array
groups = arr.reduce(function (l, r) {
    if (typeof l[r] === "undefined") {
        l[r] = 0;
    }
    l[r] += 1;

    return l;
}, {});

// extract the keys to get the number of occurrence
keys = Object.keys(groups);

// add the rows and cells (incl. rowspan)
for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    
    td_dmxn = document.createElement('td');
    td_dmxn.rowSpan = groups[keys[i]];  // add the rowspan
    td.innerHTML = keys[i];
    
    tr.appendChild(td_dmxn);
    docFragment.appendChild(tr);
}
table.appendChild(docFragment);
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the list elements by their value:

```
function groupBy(array, f) {
    var groups = {};
    array.forEach(function (o) {
        var group = JSON.stringify(f(o));
        groups[group] = groups[group] || [];
        groups[group].push(o);
    });
    return Object.keys(groups).map(function (group) {
        return groups[group];
    })
}

var arr = ['ar', 'ar', 'ar', 'ar', 'at', 'br', 'de', 'de', 'de',
    'jp', 'jp', 'us', 'us', 'us', 'us', 'us', 'us'];

arr = groupBy(arr, function (item) {
   return [item];
});

var table = document.createElement('table');
table.style.border = '1px solid black';

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    table.appendChild(tr);
    var td_dmxn = document.createElement('td');
    td_dmxn.style.border = "1px solid black";
    td_dmxn.innerHTML = arr[i];
    td_dmxn.style.textAlign = "center";
    $(tr).append(td_dmxn);
}
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3c7t9v3b/). I *think* that is what you want.

Because there is no built-in `groupBy` construct I borrowed one from this [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/37132).

Comment: how does this create `rowspan`?

Comment: @charlietfl My bad. It looks like I missed that part of the question. I _will_ update my answer but I would first please like to know, @htoniv, if this answers your question? I _suspect_ this _could_ be an example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) with regards to `rowspan`.